# How to Add Numbers in Assembly Language without using a loop?

Tags: math, assembly, x86, irvine32

I need this program to print out 1 + 3 + 4 + 10 = 18, but I haven't been successful so far. I can make it to print out 18 alone, but this is not what I am asked to do. I am not allowed to use loops. Could anyone help me with that?

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data

y1 DWORD 1
y2 DWORD 3
y3 DWORD 4
y4 DWORD 10

plus byte " + ",0
equal byte " = ",0

.code

main PROC




exit

main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Can you show more of your attempt? You mentioned being able to print out 18 alone, but your code doesn't print out anything.

Comment: What I meant is I can print out 18 as an output. But it’s not what I am asked for. Program specificly need to write 1 + 3 + 4 + 10 = 18. It’s assembly x86, win32

Comment: What lurker means is that you have not shown a single line of executable code. Please show some realistic effort toward your problem, such as including the code that prints out `18` as an output.

Comment: @Rory Daulton I will do that as long as I go home

Comment: Put the complete desired output into a string and print it.  They're all assemble-time constants anyway.  Or fully unroll a loop if you know there are 4 inputs.

Comment: @PeterCordes  I wasn't allowed to do that

Comment: @bobvance: Just FYI, the answer you posted *is* exactly my 2nd suggestion: a fully-unrolled loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it took my entire last night to figure out, but this works.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc  ; like import
.data

y1 dword 1
y2 dword 3
y3 dword 4
y4 dword 10

plus byte " + ",0
equal byte " = ",0;

.code

main PROC
    mov eax,0
    mov edx,offset plus
    mov ebx,0
    mov eax,y1
    call writedec
    add ebx,eax
    call writestring
    mov eax,y2
    call writedec
    add ebx,eax
    call writestring
     mov eax,y3
    call writedec
    add ebx,eax
    call writestring 
     mov eax,y4
    call writedec
    add ebx,eax
    mov edx,offset equal
    call writestring
    mov eax,ebx
    call writedec

   exit

main ENDP

end main
```